# Cannot deploy serverless function due to size constraint

Tags: python, deployment, scipy, vercel, aws-serverless

I am deploying a flask API on vercel, and I am getting an issue than my serverless function is greater than 50MB, and this is a limit imposed by AWS. I am using a picked Kd-Tree for nearest neighbor computations, and I am using the scipy.spatial library for it. I get the error that the build process failed, and "the serverless function "api/index" is 64.34mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb". I do not get this before installing scipy, so it must be related to that.

I cannot remove any of the other imports, and I would prefer not having to switch to a more memory efficient Kd-Tree python library without being sure of its memory usage. Is there any way to just install the Scipy Spatial library and use the Kd-Tree? Or is there a way to specify to vercel to not include the rest of the library in my project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading in, this looks like the [50MB limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) that is imposed when you directly upload zipped source code to lambda. Anything above that and source code is generally upload to S3 and referenced there instead. If you still want to keep that another option is to break out support code into [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).